# Configure Yii with Yiistrap

Tags: php, yii

I seem to have a problem configuring Yiistrap in the Yii basic template (which I used as a starting point for my web-site).

What I aim to do is adding icons in my NavBar and using an image file as the brand in the NavVar. It seems the normal NavBar of Yii is unable to do this as the "brand' option is not recognized.

So I installed YiiStrap using composer in my vendor directory. But then it is said in http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/started  to adjust my main.php file (but here isn't one)!

So basically, how do I configure this correctly so I can add the extra features in the navbar?

Kind regards

Code which I used (composer):

```
     Downloaded Yiistrap in /basic/vendor/2amigos/yiistrap
```

Config directory has these files:

```
     console.php
     db.php
     main.php
     params.php
     web.php
```

The code of main.php is

```
<?php
// main configuration
return array(

    // path aliases
    'aliases' => array(

        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/vendor/2amigos/yiistrap'), // change this if necessary
    ),
    // import paths
    'import' => array(

        'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    ),
    // application modules
    'modules' => array(

        'gii' => array(
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),
    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(

        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: please add some code which you have tried.

Comment: Added the code for you. Stackoverflow does not show the return array in the header of the file